# Service Worker "fetch" event for requesting the root path never fires

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

I am trying to set up my [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) so that it intercepts the request for the home page (ie the home page, like `www.mywebsite.com/`), which would eventually allow me to return a cached template instead. My code looks like this so far:

main.js:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
```

sw.js:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log(event.request.url)
  /**
   * only ever detects requests for resources but never the route itself..
   *
   * logged:
   * https://www.mywebsite.com/main.js
   * https://www.mywebsite.com/myimage.png
   *
   * not logged:
   * https://www.mywebsite.com/
   */
})
```

I'm pretty sure the service worker is getting set up correctly, as I am indeed detecting events being fired for requests for resources (like `/main.js` or `/myimage.png`). However, the problem is that *only* the resources' events ever get fired, even though I'd like that event for requesting the route itself (`/`) to be fired. Am I missing anything, or should I be listening for a different event?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the `register` event?

Comment: @guest271314 tried it just now but no such event is firing :\

Comment: Can you include the full code that you have tried at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 i've updated my post accordingly - thanks for your help btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that the request for the root path was in fact getting intercepted. The reason I never noticed this is because the request happens *before* the page is loaded (ie before there's even a console to log to). If I turn on the `Preserve log` feature in Chrome DevTools, I will notice the logs for the root path requests as I should.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain `.then()` to. `.register()` call then check `location.href` to determine the page at which the `ServiceWorker` has been registered

```
  navigator.serviceWorker.register("sw.js")
  .then(function(reg) {
    if (location.href === "https://www.mywebsite.com/") {
      // do stuff
      console.log(location.href, reg.scope);
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Comment: unfortunately i need to be able to access the request url while in the service worker because by the time im accessing it in main.js, the file will have already been served (i need to serve the file from the cache, not the server)

Comment: Doe the code use `fetch()` to get the `.js` and `.css` files?

Comment: it does, and that seems to be working fine. however, i wanted to detect the request url for the root path even before i fetch the `.js` and `.css`

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out, with help from https://livebook.manning.com/book/progressive-web-apps/chapter-4/27.
Here's a short version of my service worker:

```js
const cacheName = "Cache_v1";

const urlsToCache = [
 "Offline.html"
  // styles, images and scripts
 ];
 
self.addEventListener('install', (e) => 
{
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => 
    {
      return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);   
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => 
{ 
  if (e.request.url == "https://<DOMAIN_NAME>/")
  {
    console.log("root");
    e.respondWith(
      fetch("offline.html")
    );
  }
}
```